# onmouseout event happens when I am still hovering over the label

Tags: javascript

When hovering over a label, I want an image to appear and appear at the forefront of the screen. When I move off of it, I want it to disappear. My problem is when I move my mouse across the label, the image disappears and reappears really fast. Shouldn't the mouse off event, that makes the item disappear, only happen when I completely go off the label? How can I achieve this?

```
labelArray[1].onmouseover = function() {
    if (BBVar != 1)
        mouseOverOption('BB1' + group);
};
labelArray[1].onmouseout = function() {
    if ((clicked == false) && (BBVar != 1))
        mouseOffOption('BB1' + group);
};

function mouseOverOption(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById(a).style.zIndex="5";
}

function mouseOffOption(a) {
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(a).style.zIndex="0";
}
```

Comment: Can u post a jsfiddle.net example demoing the issue?

Comment: I have post it in jsfiddle to test it and the code you provided should work (I can't test your variables), but testing it whiteout them works like a charm, take a look: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3UgUe/) Maybe other thing is wrong?

Comment: There are children in my label so I bet it is the scenario described by @Armen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseout` will fire even when you are moving cursor from the target element to one of it's children.
The alternative is `mouseleave` event, unfortunately it is supported only in IE. Read more here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

If you can use jQuery, it has cross browser support for `mouseleave`:

```
$(labelArray[1]).on('mouseleave', function() {
    if ((clicked == false) && (BBVar != 1))
        mouseOffOption('BB1' + group);
});
```

In pure JS you have to check `event.relatedTarget` property to see where the mouse goes. It's hard to give an exact solution without seeing your markup.

Comment: There are children inside of it so that would explain why I am seeing this behavior. I am not too familiar with jQuery. Can I pass in a value like this: $(labelArray[1]).on('mouseleave', mouseOffOption('BB1' + group));

Comment: You can use anonymous function like this: 

`$(labelArray[1]).on('mouseleave', function() {mouseOffOption('BB1' + group)})` I updated the answer accordingly.